# Cannot query dynamically added elements

Tags: dart, dart-html

In Dart I'm trying to add HTML dynamically in a div element.

*Note: the mainContainer element is just a div in my HTML code*

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main()
{ 
  loadHTML("web/html/test.html");
}

void loadHTML(String fileName) 
{
  DivElement div = query("#mainContainer");
  div.children.clear();

  HttpRequest.getString(fileName).then((resp) {
    div.appendHtml(resp);
  });
}
```

Here is the test.html just for testing purposes

```html
<h1 id="test">test</h1>
```

The problem is when I want to query for *#test* it will not find anything

```dart
...
main()
{ 
  loadHTML("web/html/test.html");

  Element elem = query("#test");
  if (elem == null)
  {
    print("element is null");
  }
}
...
```

Is it because the HTML isn't loaded into the document yet? I'm not sure what is going on here. The actual HTML shows up in the browser however it cannot find *test*.

Using Dart SDK version 0.5.5.0_r22416

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way your code is currently organized, you're querying for `#test` before the the HTML fragment has been appended to the `div`.  If you do the stuff requiring `#test` in the callback, things should work:

```dart
HttpRequest.getString(fileName).then((resp) {
  div.appendHtml(resp);
  Element elem = query("#test");
  if (elem == null)
    print("element is null");
});
```

If it's not clear to you what's going on, your HttpRequest is asynchronous.  This is as it should be (you don't want to block while you wait on the network), but your code needs to account for this; you can't expect the fetched HTML to have been added to the page just because  `loadHTML()` has returned.